# How to change the textures of blocks without other downloads?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know there are some similar questions to this already, but none of them are quite what I'm looking for. How do I change the textures of blocks without other downloads, using a command? Is this possible? For example, how would I change the texture of a Sea Lantern to have the texture of a Barrier? I am playing on 1.9.2, if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this isn't possible and you need to download a texture pack to do that.

There may be a mod that allows you to do this I'm not sure which one though.
http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/suggestions/82649-texture-changing-with-command-blocks

Comment: This is apparently not true, I've seen world downloads that don't include texturepacks but have blocks with custom textures.

Comment: @EthanChapman Could you link to an example?

Comment: block with custom texture and texture of seaLantern are two different things.

Comment: @EthanChapman for changing textures what do you mean? Are there changed textures of actual blocks or skulls?

Answer (score 0):

### Depends on whether you want to make a resource pack yourself

The only possible way to edit the textures of a block are with a resource pack, so unfortunately, yes you will have to download a resource pack.

### But....

If you're willing to do some work, you can make a resource pack yourself. Just do a quick google search and you can see how to make your very own resource pack where you can make textures anything you want. If you're trying to make the texture of a block the same as an existing texture, that will be a lot easier considering that the texture is already made

Comment: Telling someone to google their way to an answer is not a real answer. You need to update your answer to include some sort of tutorial or something that answers the actual question.

Comment: OP wants to be able to change the textures of one block to the textures of another block, using plain vanilla commands. Resource packs do not enter into the equation at all.